# are Beam Schemas relevant in Python?

Tags: apache-beam

I'm reading the Apache Beam programming guide, which starts off very excellent but becomes a bit harder to get through starting with the Schemas section.

My main question here is: Are schemas relevant if you are using Beam in Python? It seems like they might only be relevant if you are using a strongly typed language like Java, but I'm not sure. And while the programming guide is good about using different wording for Java vs Python early on in the guide, once you get to the Schemas section it is focused entirely on Java. So it's hard for me to tell if this is a topic I should know anything about if I am using Python.

Here is the section of the guide I am asking about: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this section is missing details for Python. Schemas are definitely useful in Beam Python, however. You can do things like:

```
# Copyright 2022 Google LLC. 
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

import beam

input = beam.Row(my_first_row="x", my_second_row=1)

with beam.pipeline() as pipeline:
  (pipeline | "Create input" >> beam.Create(input) 
            | "Select output data" >> beam.Select(
               new_first_row=lambda x: "Row: " + x.my_first_row, 
               new_second_row=lambda x: x.my_second_row + 1))
```

If you're using regular beam I find this alone to make it worth using schemas. Plus when you add keys, you can keep the values as beam.Rows or list of beam.Rows which is really convenient.

That being said, if you're new to Beam, I would definitely recommend checking out Beam Dataframes in Python [[link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/#:%7E:text=The%20Apache%20Beam%20Python%20SDK,on%20the%20pandas%20DataFrame%20API.)]. This allows you operate on PCollections as if they were Pandas Dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct mapping between Python NamedTuple and Java's Schema. For Python it's especially important in the cross-language part of Beam (right now JDBC and Snowflake IOs)
For example Java's

```
Schema javaSchema = Schema.builder().addInt32Field("f_int32").build()
```

Has its equivalent in Python:

```
PythonSchema = NamedTuple("PythonSchema", [ ("f_int32", int) ]
```

The same about Row and the PythonSchema instances.

When you send the tuples in your Python transform via cross-language, e.g.:

```
pipeline | GenerateSequence(start=0, end=3)  # return some int sequence
         | Map(lambda x: PythonSchema(f_int32=x)).with_output_types(PythonSchema)
         | WriteToJdbc(...)  # cross-language transform, accepts java Row elements
```

Then WriteToJdbc will receive in its Java pipeline PCollection with objects equal to

```
Row.withSchema(javaSchema).addValue(x).build()
```

Cross-language feature is quite new and very experimental and there are little transforms that use it. But it's considered to be Beam's future and the further Python/Go transforms are going to be the cross-language ones as they require just one (mostly) Java implementation and then just a mapping to the other languages. The native transforms usually use their own data types and don't bother with Schemas AFAIK.

I wrote it in a quite hurry so if something is not clear I will edit it. I hope I helped.